# What is the name of this system of proof correction marks?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I remember in English classes when my teacher had used this sort of system when correcting essays in the class.

I never asked her about what it was and just complied and made the revisions to my essay according to the markings.

I'm quite interested in this subject now—I've illustrated a reference of it and linked to it below. Can anyone tell me the name of this system, and where can I learn more about it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This paper (PDF)](http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~bstahl/CORRECTION_MARKS.pdf) lists what it calls the "British standard institution proof correction marks". I can see your "Capitalise" mark on the list, but not the other two.

Merriam-Webster offers [this list](http://www.merriam-webster.com/mw/table/proofrea.htm) of proofreaders' marks.

**Edit:** Courtesy of Kosmonaut, here's a link to [Proofreader’s and Editor’s Symbols](http://ucommunications.colorado.edu/services/style-guide/proofreaders-and-editors-symbols) over at University of Colorado. All three of your symbols are on that list.

[image: Proofreader's and editor's symbols]

Comment: Ahh... Yes-I had been in an American school then, so perhaps that was only used for English for the American Curriculum.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally heard these symbols (and more) referred to as **proofreaders' marks** or **copyeditors' marks**, and they're taught in copyediting classes. They are becoming less common as more copyediting is done electronically, using track changes in Word or other word processing programs.