# use of => symbol

Tags: symbols

For years I have used '=>' as a sign meaning 'should be changed to' and I have long since forgotten whether this is a personal idiosyncrasy or an actual existing usage.

*e.g.*  "in the sentence above word 'jive' => 'jibe.'"

Is this familiar usage to anyone?
Anyone else besides me, I mean.

Comment: I use this sign as "result".

Comment: Related: [Symbols/Markings in Correcting Grammar/English in Essays Used by Teachers?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/symbols-markings-in-correcting-grammar-english-in-essays-used-by-teachers)

Comment: @RegDwight, hm, don't see => or ⇒ there.

Comment: More anecdotal tales: I wouldn't know that this symbol meant anything in particular without context. The full sentence "In the sentence above, jive => jibe" provides enough context for me to know what was meant.

Comment: @Unreason: precisely my point.

Answer (score 12):

In logic it is used for implication, as shown in the table of symbols given by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols):

- *p implies q* is denoted with p ⇒ q

This is the 'demands' sense of 'implies', not the 'suggests'. If statement p is true, it necessarily follows that statement q is also true.

Comment: Even outside of mathematics, the only sense I've known this symbol to be used for is "implies".

Comment: And other fields of maths, and also science, whether the user is thinking about implication (semantically/syntactically) or just some loose idea of deduction.

Comment: 'In logic it is used for implication' ⇏ 'It is not used otherwise elsewhere'. The spacing tilde (~), for example, has quite a range of different usages even in maths and related fields. The body question, not just the title question, needs addressing.

Answer (score 2):

In a regular text, I'd simply take it to mean **changes/changed into**, just like any random arrow, without any sense of desirability. Your particular interpretation is unfamiliar to me, and I believe it is not generally so used. Practice may be different in specific fields.

Of course you could indicate a desirable change with it, but I don't believe this desirability is inherent in the symbol.

As Unreason says, it means implication in formal logic: *p => q* means "if p, then q", just as *p <=> q* means "if p, then q; and if q, then p".

Answer (score 2):

The usage is familiar to me also, but I don't know accepted it is. I don't know the approved editorial marks for paper proofreading ([proofreading marks](http://www.espressographics.com/text/proofreader.html), but I've used '=>' in electronic text to say what I think should be done.

Which is to say, it is a reasonable symbol to mean "should be changed to", but therer is no official support for it that I know of.

('=>' has a technical but **unrelated** meaning in mathematical logic for a very specific kind of implication)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not → [->] rather than ⇒ [=>]? The first one usually mean to substitute in place of the other.